# Set switch to mute on a video background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I want to set a switch or button to mute on a video background in swift 3+

CODE:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftVideoBackground

class ViewController: UIViewController {
private let videoBackground = VideoBackground()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    videoBackground.play(view: view, videoName: "intro", videoType: "mp4", isMuted: false, alpha : 0.25, willLoopVideo : true)
}

}
```

Comment: `Lol` all are negatives ... The `question` and `answers`. Still there is an accepted answer?

Comment: @TheTiger: my code works for him only but nobody wants me to answer for this type of question thats why negatives . LoL

Answer (score -1):

//Add this method to VideoBackground class

```
public var isMuted = true {
        didSet {
            playerLayer.player?.isMuted = isMuted
        }
    }
```

//Button action method

```
@IBAction func mute(_ sender: Any) {
    videoBackground.isMuted = true
}
```

// when app is in background

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    videoBackground.pause() // OR videoBackground.isMuted = true
}
```

Comment: Value of type 'VideoBackground' has no member 'isMuted'

Comment: please add the first method to VideoBackground class. Just updated and let me know if you find any error

Comment: thank you, it works.. if i want to remove the mute? like a cycle

Comment: where ever you want to remove mute just add videoBackground.isMuted = false

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION:

SOLUTION:

```
 import UIKit
 import SwiftVideoBackground
 import AVFoundation




class ViewController: UIViewController {
private let videoBackground = VideoBackground()

@IBAction func `switch`(_ sender: UISwitch) {

    if (sender.isOn == true)
    {
        videoBackground.isMuted = true
    }
    else
    {
        videoBackground.isMuted = false
    }

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    videoBackground.play(view: view, videoName: "intro", videoType: "mp4", isMuted: false, alpha : 0.25, willLoopVideo : true)
}

}
```